# Why my char array's elements are changing outside the for loop?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, buffer, file-processing

So I tried to get the codewords from a file and put them into my words array. When I print them inside the for loop I get all the codewords from the .txt file but when I try to print one of the elements of my array, it always gives the last line from the text file. How can I fix this?

This is my text file's content:
ape
car
big
123
book
door
epic
band
test
apple
catch
super
level
small
basket
abroad
action
carbon
program
buzzcut
jimjams
muzzles
puzzles
dazzled
football
baseball
absolute
campaign
casualty
division
quizzical
twizzling
bedazzled
fuzziness
maximizer
strawberry
friendship
motivation
everything ==> each word in an another line.

```
char *words[0][39];

int main() {
    FILE *codewordsPtr;

    if((codewordsPtr = fopen("codewords.txt","rb")) == NULL){
        printf("file could not be opened");
    }

    char bum[12];
    int wordList = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<20; i+=5,wordList++){
        fseek(codewordsPtr, i, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(bum, 12, codewordsPtr);
        words[0][wordList] = bum;
        printf("%s" ,words[0][wordList]);
    }

    for(int i=20; i<50; i+=6,wordList++){
        fseek(codewordsPtr, i, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(bum, 12, codewordsPtr);
        words[0][wordList] = bum;
        printf("%s" ,words[0][wordList]);
    }

    for(int i=50; i<85; i+=7,wordList++){
        fseek(codewordsPtr, i, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(bum, 12, codewordsPtr);
        words[0][wordList] = bum;
        printf("%s" ,words[0][wordList]);
    }

    for(int i=85; i<117; i+=8,wordList++){
        fseek(codewordsPtr, i, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(bum, 12, codewordsPtr);
        words[0][wordList] = bum;
        printf("%s" ,words[0][wordList]);
    }

    for(int i=117; i<171; i+=9,wordList++){
        fseek(codewordsPtr, i, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(bum, 12, codewordsPtr);
        words[0][wordList] = bum;
        printf("%s" ,words[0][wordList]);
    }

    for(int i=171; i<231; i+=10,wordList++){
        fseek(codewordsPtr, i, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(bum, 12, codewordsPtr);
        words[0][wordList] = bum;
        printf("%s" ,words[0][wordList]);
    }

    for(int i=231; i<286; i+=11,wordList++){
        fseek(codewordsPtr, i, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(bum, 12, codewordsPtr);
        words[0][wordList] = bum;
        printf("%s" ,words[0][wordList]);
    }

    for(int i=286; i<334; i+=12,wordList++){
        fseek(codewordsPtr, i, SEEK_SET);
        fgets(bum, 12, codewordsPtr);
        words[0][wordList] = bum;
        printf("%s" ,words[0][wordList]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("%s", words[0][5]);

    fclose(codewordsPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output: ape
car
big
123
book
door
epic
band
test
apple
catch
super
level
small
basket
abroad
action
carbon
program
buzzcut
jimjams
muzzles
puzzles
dazzled
football
baseball
absolute
campaign
casualty
division
quizzical
twizzling
bedazzled
fuzziness
maximizer
everything

everything
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.015 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: `char *words[0][39];` 0 sized arrays are not allowed in standard C.

Comment: @Berk Ustuner  Also you are setting elements of the two-dimensional array to the address of the same array bum words[0][wordList] = bum;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow So how can I store the words in my text file in an array?

Comment: Could you show your file's contents? Those magic number loops look needlessly rigid, and whatever you are trying to do could likely be solved more simply with better file formatting.

Comment: @BerkUstuner You need to allocate memory for each word.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks, I guess I need memory allocation. I thougth I could escape using it :)

Comment: Use `strcpy()` of one of it's friends to copy strings.  Make sure there is space allocated.  Maybe you should be using `strdup()`.

Comment: @BerkUstuner Your file has consistent formatting - there is no need for the complicated loops and manual seeking through the file! Something as simple as `char a_word[64]; while (1 == fscanf(file, "%63s", a_word)) { /* do something with the buffer */ }` will get you each word in that file. It's up to you to allocate space (dynamically or statically), and **copy** the *contents* of the buffer each iteration.